# Using Stokes' Theorem to evaluate $\int_{C} \textbf{F} d\textbf{r}$ given $\textbf{F} = (z^2, 2x, y^2)$ and $S: 1-x^2-y^2$ for $z \geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I am asked to find $\int_{C} \textbf{F} d\textbf{r}$ using Stokes' Theorem given $\textbf{F} = (z^2, 2x, y^2)$ and $S: z = 1-x^2-y^2$ for $z \geq 0$.

I am proceeding that calculation in two ways:

**Using $\displaystyle \int_{C} \textbf{F} d\textbf{r}$**

$$\int_{C} \textbf{F} d\textbf{r}=\int_{C} \textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t)) \cdot \textbf{r'}(t) dt= \begin{bmatrix}
x= \cos t\\
y= \sin t
\end{bmatrix} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (0,2\cos t, \sin^2 t) \cdot (-\sin t, \cos t, 0) dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} 2\cos^2 t dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1+\cos 2t dt =2\pi$$

Which is the correct answer (according to the textbook)

**Using $\displaystyle \iint_S curl \ \textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{S}$**

$$P=(x,y,1-x^2-y^2) \quad \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=(1,0,-2x) \quad \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=(0,1,-2y)$$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = (1,0,-2x) \times (0,1,-2y)=(2x,2y,1)$$

And exactly on this step I am not sure what I should do: to evaluate the $curl \textbf{F}$ should I use

$$curl \ \textbf{F}= \begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
z^2 & 2x & y^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

or

$$curl \ \textbf{F}= \begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
(1-x^2-y^2)^2 & 2x & y^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Is $C$ the boundary of $S$?

Comment: Yes (I fixed the equation for S, thank you)

Comment: No, this is wrong, @EdMo38. You need to compute the curl with $x,y,z$ in there and only substitute the parametrization afterwards!!!